# Get string in the nth position if contains a substring

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, find, substring

in column B I have a string divided by the "|" delimiter. One and only one of the parts inside each "|" contains the word "Above".
[image]
In the example I shared the part inside "|" that contains the word "Above" is string5, because there are 4 "|" before it + 2 "|" after it.
meaning:
[image]
I want a formula to get the answer **string5**
Would love to get your help.

Here the solution, credit to @JvdVL:
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE([@[Image URL]],"|",REPT(" ",LEN([@[Image URL]]))),(LEN(LEFT([@[Image Caption]],FIND("Above",[@[Image Caption]])-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT([@[Image Caption]],FIND("Above",[@[Image Caption]])-1),"|","")))*LEN([@[Image URL]])+1,LEN([@[Image URL]])))

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) answers your question.

Comment: Not really what I had in mind but if you solved your own problem that's great!

Comment: I was on the right way but my formula was twice as long as the end result here, and this is much simpler. Cheers.

Comment: If you scroll down in the linked q&a you'll see it can be done even more effectively using Filterxml.